# Как убрать или уменьшить зазор между Bootstrap колонками?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть Bootstrap код  с колонками

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--My Code -->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-center bg-white">
    <div class=" row col-md-7" style="height: 100vh">
    
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-success m-0 p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div> 
      
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-primary m-0 p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-danger p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div>
      
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Между колонками  *зазоры* не понятно как они получились, классы `m-0,p-0` не действуют.

Как *убрать* или *уменьшить* зазоры между колонками  *оставив высоту прежней* ?

Comment: .h-25{height: auto!important;min-height: 25%!important;}

Comment: Зазоры все еще остаются

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте `align-content: baseline;` сюда:

```
 <div class=" row col-md-7" style="height: 100vh; align-content: baseline;">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--My Code -->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-center bg-white">
    <div class=" row col-md-7" style="height: 100vh; align-content: baseline;">
    
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-success m-0 p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div> 
      
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-primary m-0 p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 h-25 bg-danger p-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis 
         animi voluptates nisi fugiat rerum nam, repellat sint facere, eius 
          at provident 
      </div>
      
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```